# Secure copy over two IPs on the same network to the local machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scp

I am trying to write a bash script to ssh first into IP1(asks for a password) from my localhost machine and then ssh into IP2. Once in IP2 I want to scp to my local machine.

```
IP1=192.168.10.10
IP2=192.168.10.9

ssh root@$IP1
ssh root@$IP2

cd /var/log

scp message* localuser@$localIP:/home/localuser/Desktop/MessageFolder/
```

The above is what I currently have to do manually via the command line in Linux

I do not have direct access to IP2. Think of it as a backdoor. IP2 has a password, IP1 does not.

Is there any way to do this? I have more code written if this isn't helpful.

Can someone verify if I can do something similar to what was done for this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine

I've also heard of port forwarding... How would that work with this example?

I'm very new to bash scripting and would appreciate some patience

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).